# ajax not working in plugin

Tags: jquery

The code below works beautifully outside of WordPress but as soon as I attempt to execute it inside of WordPress nothing happens:

```
var js = jQuery.noConflict();
js(document).ready(function(){
    js('#ClientID').live('change', function() {
        js.ajax({
            url     : 'includes/form.php',
            type    : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : js('#myform').serialize(),
            success: function( data ) {
                   for(var id in data) {        
                        js(id).val( data[id] );                    
                   }
                 }
        });
    });
});
```

I have triple checked everything, I've put an alert just above js.ajax and it executes, however if it's inside of the js.ajax({ it doesnt do anything. I'm at a loss at why this isn't working.

Comment: Have you considered using Admin Ajax instead?

Comment: Have you debugged this in a browser console?  I'm wondering if any data is being POSTed by jQuery ...

Comment: You are probably posting to the wrong URL. Check your console, you will probably get 404 response from the server. I suggest you rewrite your functions based on the articles suggested by others.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would recommend you to look through [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) article. If it doesn't help, take in consideration these articles as well:

- [Simplified AJAX For WordPress Plugin Developers using Jquery](http://amiworks.co.in/talk/simplified-ajax-for-wordpress-plugin-developers-using-jquery/)
- [jQuery and Ajax in WordPress Plugins – Administration Pages](http://xplus3.net/2008/10/16/jquery-and-ajax-in-wordpress-plugins-administration-pages/)
- [jQuery and Ajax in WordPress Plugins – Public Pages](http://xplus3.net/2008/10/27/jquery-and-ajax-in-wordpress-plugins-public-pages/)